# Употребление инфинитива в качестве косвенного дополнения

Tags: грамматика

В английском языке допустимо сказать, например: "They were depending on me to look after little Ivan"

Можно ли аналогично выразить это предложение в русском языке через инфинитив?

"Они положились на меня последить за маленьким Иваном"

Или единственный способ - это придаточное предложение?

"Они положились на меня, чтобы я последил за маленьким Иваном"

Comment: есть вариант вместо инфинитива использовать существительное, хотя в русском это не всегда удобно стилистически: ***В присмотре / В том, что касается/касалось присмотра за маленьким Иваном они полностью зависели от меня.***

Answer (score 6):

**Они доверили мне присмотреть за маленьким Ванюшей.**

В русском языке тоже существуют фразы модальной семантики с инфинитивом. Например,

> **попросили** присмотреть
>
> **предложили** пойти
>
> **дали** поспать
>
> **дали возможность** поступить
>
> **разрешили** принести
>
> **позволили** высказаться
>
> **вынудили** принять меры
>
> **заставили** извиниться

Answer (score 1):

Оба приведённые вами предложения неправильные, нельзя сказать ни "положились последить" ни "положились, чтобы я проследил" - так попросту не говорят. Если ваш вопрос заключается в том, бывают ли в принципе конструкции с инфинитивом, то конечно бывают, но вот конкретно в этом случае кто-то может сказать "Они очень рассчитывали на то, что я присмотрю за Ваней".